# Concatenate Strings in Alphabetical Order

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access, vba

I am trying to concatenate strings from two separate columns. The trouble is, I need the first string in the concatenation to be the first alphabetically.

For Example:

```
Column 1        Column 2        Concatenation
def             abc             abcdef
abc             def             abcdef
```

Is there any way to do this within Access? SQL Server may also be an option, but it would be much easier for me to stay within Access.

Answer (score 3):

For two strings, you can stay in Access:

```
select iif(column1 < column2, column1 & column2, column2 & column1) as concatenation
```

If you had more than two strings in the row, then SQL Server would be a much better option.

Answer (score 2):

Sql Server version

```
create table a
(col1 nvarchar(100)
 ,col2 nvarchar(100)
 )
 insert into a values('abc','def')
 insert into a values('def','abgggccz')
 insert into a values('xyzabc','def')
 insert into a values('def','xyzabc')
 insert into a values('axyzabc','def')
 insert into a values('adef','acxyzabc')
 insert into a values('abcd','x')
```

Query

```
select 
case when 
LOWER(col1)>LOWER(col2)
then col2+''+col1
else
col1+''+col2
end
from a
```

result

```
abcdef
abgggcczdef
defxyzabc
defxyzabc
axyzabcdef
acxyzabcadef
abcdx
```

note : if you are using sql server then you can do the same if you want to concatenate more than 2 strings